# How to make external emoticons on Lync

Tags: silverlight, lync, emoticons, lync-client-sdk

I want to make external emoticons(I got images, like jpeg, png, whatever I want to import),
 and I want to import to Microsoft Lync application.

I heard that there is a Lync SDK for developing Lync application, but I don't know it can be used what I want to make.

Does anybody have any idea use external emoticons in my chat on Lync?

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely create a lync client using the lync SDK and replace certain placeholders like :mynewemoticon: with an image.

You'd have to Listen to the conversation events and do the replace on the Conversation's MessageReceived events.

Transferring images through the existing lync requires setting up a sort of tcp file transfer and is not really what you're after.

Comment: Lync can send HTML messages. I have not tried, but you could attempt to use the client SDK to catch the messages and replace placeholders with `<img .. />` html codes before handing them to the client to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the existing Lync client to do this - none of the SDKs are designed to let you modify the client in this way.

As Chris has already said, if you *really* want to achieve this then you'd have to write your own Lync client...which you can do using the Lync Client SDK and UI Suppression Mode. But, you'd then be responsible for writing all parts of the client: signing in, sending and receiving messages, handling calls, conferences, etc.